# ContentPresenter layout pass

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, profiler

I am trying to profile wpf application (to speed up `ListView` displaying complex multi-column datatemplated items). And I have problem to understand figures in application timeline report:

[image]

Description says:

[image]

Here is this column template (xaml):

```xml
<GridViewColumn Header="Header">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
```

Questions:

- What means "Element" as a type of timeline item? Is it layout pass (as I understand it) or is it something else?
- Why sum of children ( only one child = 0.33 ms) is not equal total time (7.82 ms) ?
- What `ContentPresenter` was doing for 7.5 ms?

Comment: To answer your 2nd point, the `Element` its self does work in addition to its 3 children.  The sum would include the work done for the parent.  You can see that in the description screenshot, where it lists Duration (total) and Duration (self) as separate times.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, ContentPresenter can have just one child (expanded `StackPanel` is parent of another `StackPanel` and 2 `Canvas`). Nwm that. You are right, *self time* clearly shows a time spend by `ContentPresenter` itself. To do what? Is datatemplating that expensive?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "children and grandchildren", also, I can't count.  I'm not sure what it is actually doing in there that would make it take so long.

Comment: Just for giggles, if you set some hard coded sizes on those children does it have a positive result in reducing that footprint? I know I'll run into something like this at some point so I'm really curious too. +1 great question.

Comment: @ChrisW., it doesn't seems to do anything with children layout. I tried to set fixed size for first `StackPanel`, it still take 0.3 ms for it and 7.5 ms for `ContentPresenter`. If I make datatemplate empty (by removing `StackPanel` completely) it's less than 0.01 ms. It seems this time includes bindings creation and all other things. I am trying to pin the most time-eating part of that item.

Comment: Ah right on, I thought you literally just had some panels in there and there was some sort of weird measure/arrange thing going on. Didn't think about any kind of bindings etc from the snippet.

Comment: @ChrisW., I've asked a wrong question, right one is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38248842/1997232). Still this one worth the answer I think if somebody else made similar conclusion.

Comment: Is 7 ms really your biggest performance concern? I could understand if it were called 1000+ times, but according to your screen shot, its called once.  I believe your first and second questions have been answered. The answer to your final question is to profile the actual .net framework code and see what its doing.

Comment: @Taekahn, 7 ms per cell. Multiply by columns (*10), multiply by number of visible items (*50), do this every-time when scrolling/loading view... Do you know how to profile framework? I don't. And I was expecting for some hints here, like: "check your bindings aren't expensive", because indeed there was one binding what was very expensive (enumerating files), the problem is what such errors are not visible immediately (it wasn't in the first row shown in question).