# Performance: Binding vs code-behind

Tags: c#, performance, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I'd like to improve the performance of my Xamarin.Forms app (based on MVVM pattern). Now, I have bindings to my all static label from viewmodel.

View (XAML):

```
<Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
public string Text => CustomResourceManager.Current.Get(nameof(UserInterface.Text));
```

I was wondering if changing it to something like this can be faster.

View (XAML):

```
<Label x:Name="TextLabel" />
```

Code-behind:

```
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    TextLabel.Text = CustomResourceManager.Current.Get(nameof(UserInterface.Text));
}
```

Do you have any experience or what is the simpler way to validate my refactor idea?

Comment: Second approach *"has less overhead than binding"* (from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/performance)). But the real question is do you have performance issues? I have no expertise in xamarin, but in wpf you can easily create [custom markup extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23372411/1997232) to reduce amount of code if all labels text is retrieved similarly.

Comment: I know that something like this is faster: Button.Text = "Accept", but in my case I have to obtain this from my CustomResourceManager and set from code-behind. I assume that the time to obtain string from CustomResourceManager is const and doesn't depend on MVVM or code-behind.
I'm looking for a way to improve performance because views in my app are complicated and even 50 ms while rendering increase user feelings.

Comment: Do you already identify the bottleneck? Use profiler if not. I doubt the simple bindings like above will matter, thought everybody has to [ask his performance question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38248842/1997232).

Comment: _"I was wondering if changing it to something like this can be faster."_ -- [there's only one way to find out](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not so relevant, because after all the components are going to use Binding for all the values you didn't set by your self, Binding is always going to be used by the framework more than your code